# Iron Router routing to new collection document url dynamically

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have a goals mongo collection.

I am using Iron Router to navigate to each goal document via '/goals/:_id'

This works great for clicking around the app.

However, when a user adds a new goal to the collection (via server Insert method), I'd like to automatically navigate to that page at the same time.

**On the client:**

```
'click #new-goal': () ->
    Meteor.call("newGoal", (error, result) ->
        Router.go('/goal/#{result}')
        console.log "#{result} created and user redirected.")
```

The newGoal method runs on the server and Router.go is run before the callback returns.

Should I be using "waitOn" or is there a better implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Coffeescript indents. The Router.go shouldn't happen before the callback.

---

On the argument about what Meteor docs say, here is the snippet from documents:

> When the method is complete (which may or may not happen before Meteor.call returns), the callback will be called with two arguments: error and result. If an error was thrown, then error will be the exception object. Otherwise, error will be undefined and the return value (possibly undefined) will be in result.

What does it mean?

1. The code following the Meteor.call will run before the method returns (that does not include the code that is inside the callback).
2. The callback will not run until the the server side method is complete (it's logical since response or error cannot be provided before method is complete. It is also in line with the observed behavior. Additionally, it is inline with the actual meteor code [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js#L1466)

Comment: When Meteor.call is called from the client it always runs async, so the Router.go running before the method happens (and the local cache is updated) is quite natural and understandable, Meteor.call only blocks when you run it from the server without a callback.

Comment: If you look at the code, Router.go is inside the callback. Callback wouldn't run until Meteor.call has returned. Or someone rewrote the definition of callback while I was looking away?

Comment: Dumb.  The issue wasn't the Router.go - it was the route using single quotes.  Single quotes don't solve for #{}.  Changed to double and life is good.  Thanks all!

Comment: I think you are misreading the documents and my answer. See the updated answer